# How to display and read a float in a non english (german) ionic 3 app?

Tags: ionic-framework

In an ionic 3 app I am currently trying to get a floating point number as user input. Since the application is exclusively targeting a german audience I am expecting input with a comma as the decimal separator, e.g. `750,5`.
In addition I would like to open the numerical keyboard.

I tried including an input field with `type="text"`. I parsed the resulting input string using a custom parsing method, which respects the different decimal separator.

Since the input field has a two way binding and the application might change the number itself I convert the number to a string using the Angular decimal pipe like so:

```
numberString = new DecimalPipe('de').transform(value.count, '1.0-2');
```

That worked well, however the app always opens the full alphanumerical keyboard.

To show the numerical keyboard I used the input field with `type="number"`.

```html
<ion-input type="number" step="any"></ion-input>
```

Using this, the numerical shows as expected. However the input field now includes thousand separators. For example if I type `7500`, the input field displays `7,500` using the English decimal separator.

Now I am not sure where this problem is caused but the app itself seems to be running under an English locale although the device is set to German. I expect the problem to be solved by setting the web view locale to German. How could I achieve this?